# .htaccess to redirect "/whatever" links to a subdirectory

Tags: .htaccess

I coded a website assuming the test server would be something like (http://test.domain.com), however, it ended up being at http://www.domain.com/test. I don't have access to the hosting panel to create a subdomain, whatsoever.

The .htaccess file has to reside in /test/ and all links such as href="/css/style.css" should load from "/test/css/style.css.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

if you do something like this..

```
RewriteRule ^css/style.css$ /test/css/style.css [L]
```

as you can see, you can only redirect from that directory (where the .htaccess is at) and under, not above

so, i don't think it'll work, because you need access to `/` and not just `/test/`